# Twitter sharing problems with umlauts ä & ö

Tags: encoding, twitter, character-encoding, diacritics

I'm having trouble sharing messages containing scandinavian ä & ö to twitter through a share-button on my site. If I use UTF8-codes above %7F, i just bump into an "Invalid Unicode value in one or more parameters" error.

An example: http://twitter.com/home/?status=%40user+blah%26%E4

I've tried a bunch of different encodings, but none seem to work with ä, ö etc.

Anyone found a solution for this?

Edit:
Part of this problem is related to what address you link your share-tweet. Links to http://twitter.com/home/?status=%40user+blah%26%E4%C3%A4
and 
http://www.twitter.com/home/?status=%40user+blah%26%E4%C3%A4
Yield very different results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UTF-8 represents code points above U+007F using more than one byte. So when you want ä (U+00E4), the UTF-8 representation is the two bytes C3 A4 and thus the percent-encoding is %C3%A4. A handy website that will help you with these conversions is https://www.url-encode-decode.com